# What actually it means by the words “define the orthogonal projection in the spectral decomposition”?

Tags: linear-algebra, terminology

Define the orthogonal projection in the spectral decomposition for the $2 \times 2$ matrix $ \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 1 \\ 1 & 2 \end{bmatrix}$.

**Answer:**

I can find the orthogonal projection of the above matrix.

Also I can find the spectral decomposition of the above matrix.

But I do not understand the question's meaning.

What actually it means by the word $ \text{define the orthogonal projection in the spectral decomposition}$ ?

Help me

Comment: That's more than one word.

Comment: @what can be the  meanings?

Comment: I guess the question says " find spectral decomposition of $A=\lambda_1P_{\lambda_1}+\cdots+\lambda_nP_{\lambda_n}$ where $P_{\lambda}$ denotes orthogonal projection onto $\textbf{eigenspace}$ $V_{\lambda}$ ".

Comment: @YadatiKiran, write clearly and also mention what do you mean by $V_{\lambda}$?

Answer (score 1):

I presume the question requires to find orthogonal projections $P_{\lambda}$ in the spectral decomposition $$\fbox{$A=\lambda_1P_{\lambda_1}+\cdots+\lambda_nP_{\lambda_n}$} $$ where $P_{\lambda}$ denotes the orthogonal projection onto eigenspace  $V_{\lambda}$.

$\text{( I am giving details for the ones who do not know )}$

The eigenvalues and corresponding eigenvectors are $\lambda=3\:,\:\lambda=1$ with $\displaystyle V_{\lambda_3}=\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix}$ and $\displaystyle V_{\lambda_1}=\begin{bmatrix}1\\-1\end{bmatrix}$. The projection matrix onto $V_{\lambda}$ is given by $$\fbox{$P=V_{\lambda}(V_{\lambda}^TV_{\lambda})^{-1}V_{\lambda}^T$} $$ We have $$P_{\lambda_3}=\begin{bmatrix}\dfrac12 &\dfrac12\\\dfrac12 &\dfrac12\end{bmatrix}\:\text{ and}\: P_{\lambda_1}=\begin{bmatrix}\dfrac12 &\dfrac{-1}{2}\\\dfrac{-1}{2}&\dfrac12\end{bmatrix}$$

The spectral decomposition of $A$ is $$A=3\cdot \begin{bmatrix}\dfrac12 &\dfrac12\\\dfrac12 &\dfrac12\end{bmatrix}+1\cdot\begin{bmatrix}\dfrac12 &\dfrac{-1}{2}\\\dfrac{-1}{2}&\dfrac12\end{bmatrix}  $$